# How to remove List<int[]> from another List<int[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, list

This is the aftermath from my previous question 
[How to remove int[] from List<int[]>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997483/how-to-remove-int-from-listint/30997772?noredirect=1#comment50024775_30997772)

I'm now trying remove a list of int[]s inside a List int[].

```
int[] t1 = new int[] { 0, 2 };
        List<int[]> trash = new List<int[]>()
        {
            t1,
            new int[] {0,2},
            new int[] {1,0},
            new int[] {1,1}
        };
        List<int[]> trash2 = new List<int[]>()
        {
            new int[] {0,1},
            new int[] {1,0},
            new int[] {1,1}
        };

        MessageBox.Show(trash.Count + "");
        trash.RemoveRange(trash2);
        MessageBox.Show(trash.Count + "");
```

I tried to add all the int[] from trash2 to trash array and then removed items  with the same value from the trash2 array but, it only remove the first int[]s from the trash2.

is their any other way of removing List arrays from List arrays?

Comment: what expected output for your sample?

Comment: @DimiToulakis, are you try it with array as element type?

Comment: I want to remove all int[] with the same value as the int[]s of the second array. Which in other term, I want to have a list of int[] from the differences between two List int[]

Comment: I would suggest using `.Except` with an `IEqualityComparer` written for `int[]`.

Comment: Is the order in the list relevant? Is the order in the arrays relevant? You should show the expected result for your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is your answer

```
int[] t1 = new int[] { 0, 2 };
List<int[]> trash = new List<int[]>()
{
    t1,
    new int[] {0,2},
    new int[] {1,0},
    new int[] {1,1}
};
List<int[]> trash2 = new List<int[]>()
{
    new int[] {0,1},
    new int[] {1,0},
    new int[] {1,1}
};

Console.WriteLine(trash.Count + "");//Count = 4
trash.RemoveAll(a => trash2.Any(b => b.SequenceEqual(a)));
Console.WriteLine(trash.Count + "");//Count = 2
```

Some **SequenceEqual** logic is mentioned in previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997772/1660178

Comment: at the given link which contains my prev post. someone suggested this answer But admit that this works slower than other methods, But Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Another approach involves the use of the `.Except` extension method, and a custom `IEqualityComparer`. The following code also produces the result you need:

```
public class IntArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] x)
    {
        return x.Aggregate((t,i) => t + i.GetHashCode());
    }
}  

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] t1 = new int[] { 0, 2 };
        List<int[]> trash = new List<int[]>()
        {
            t1,
            new int[] {0,2},
            new int[] {1,0},
            new int[] {1,1}
        };

        List<int[]> trash2 = new List<int[]>()
        {
            new int[] {0,1},
            new int[] {1,0},
            new int[] {1,1}
        };

        var difference = trash.Except(trash2, new IntArrayComparer()).ToArray();
    }
}
```